# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802) - when reading data from table

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application , i am getting data from web services and storing it in some tables. i am doing this in IntentService.Everything is working fine.

But when i read records from table by using query

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

I am getting following exception.

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:843)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
```

Kindly help

Comment: please your database code

Comment: where did you called database.rawQuery(query, null);?

Comment: 1802 is SQLITE_IOERR_FSTAT.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the database using `db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` before the reading from database